# XPath Evaluation without DOM in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I'm working on a .NET project that requires XPath evaluation over documents, but that **must not** load the XML DOM in memory, where cases are that the contents to analyze can be of big dimensions (in the order of gigabytes).
This is closer to the SAX model that is more common in Java, but it's not very common in .NET.

Back in the days, someone at GotDotNet created a nice library (still downloadable at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22677) named XPathReader, which mimics the SAX model, evaluating XPath expressions in a forward-only direction, that is pretty much what I'm looking for.
I see that Microsoft has developed the concept also inside BizTalk (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/momalek/archive/2011/12/21/streamed-xpath-extraction-using-hidden-biztalk-class-xpathreader.aspx), which seems logic in that context, but it hasn't make it a general purpose library anywhere.

Since the XPathReader library is unmaintained since 2004 (11 years!), I'm wondering if any other effort is known on this field, that copes with more support behind and more in sync versions.

Thanks for all your input!

Comment: When you say GB do you have a upper limit in mind, i.e. are we talking low 1-10GB files here or 20+GB?

Comment: Acually it's a system that reads among scattered binary serialized data, so that the XML reader is built in forward-only mode, from an underlying system.
A single document could reach even gigabytes scattered between machines (shards). It's purely theoretical about the size, but a system like this must have no hard limits on size

Comment: You probably solved this months ago (if so, @Antonello, please put your solution in the answer box and accept it...) but if not, SaxonEE (XSLT) has a streaming mode, or if you will process the same document multiple times, use an XML database and XQuery, e.g. with XQSharp or BaseX.

Comment: Actually, my interest is related to the fact that I develop the project DeveelDB (http://github.com/deveel/deveeldb) and I wanted to support XML data types. In a database context, the search on the fields must be fast, doesn't have to create memory peaks. That is why I'm interested in the model. I will check the links you provided me, but SaxonEE is not an option, because of the licensing